# Combinatorics problem mapping surjective functions with conditions

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

**The prompt is to find the number go surjections $f$ mapping $\{1, 2, \dotsc , 13 \}$ onto $\{1, 2, \dotsc , 10\}$ such that for every $x \in \{1, 2, 3\}$, $|f^{-1}(\{x\})| = 2$ and for every $x \in \{1, 2, \dotsc, 12\}$, $f(x) \neq x+1$.**

The way I solved this problem was splitting it into two parts.

Let $A = \{1, 2, \dotsc, 13\}$ and $B = \{1, 2, \dotsc, 10\}$.

- For $x \in \{1, 2, ..., 12\}$, $f(x) \neq (x + 1)$:

  So there are $12$ elements elements that can't be mapped onto $B$ from $A$ which are one more that the element. Since there are only $10$ elements in $B$, there are $9$ elements which can't be mapped onto $B$. e.g. $f(1) \neq 2, f(2) \neq 3, \dotsc, f(9) \neq 10$.

  Using permutations we know that there are $13^{10} - 9$ such ways.
- For $x \in \{1, 2, 3\}$, $|f^{-1}(\{x\})| = 2$:

  This means for elements $1$, $2$ and $3$ in $B$, the function $f$ should map to element $2$ in $A$.

  This is possible in choosing $3$ elements in $B$ as $\binom{10}{3}$ ways and mapping onto $1$ elements on $A$ chosen in $\binom{13}{1}$ ways, making it $\binom{10}{3}\cdot\binom{13}{1}$ ways to do this? Or should it be only $3$ ways?

Making the final solutions the sum of $2$ answers we found, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right path.

**Edit**

I tried attempting this problem using inclusion-exclusion principle making 3 cases,

1. For x = 1, $f^{-1}(1)$ can be chosen in $\binom{13}{2}$ ways, since x-1 = 0 cannot be chosen, which doesn't exist anyways.
2. For x = 2, $f^{-1}(1)$ can be chosen in $\binom{12}{2}$ ways, since x-1 = 1 cannot be chosen hence have 12 elements in A.
3. For x = 3, $f^{-1}(1)$ can be chosen in $\binom{12}{2}$ ways, since x-1 = 2 cannot be chosen hence have 12 elements in A.

Now for conditions 1 and 2 together, $f^{-1}(1)$ and $f^{-1}(2)$ can be chosen in $\binom{13}{2}\cdot\binom{11}{2}$ ways, since after mapping 2 elements from A to x = 1, we are left with 11 elements, for x = 2 to choose, from which we cannot choose the element 1 since 2-1 = 1.

Following the same pattern, we have

- $f^{-1}(2)$ and $f^{-1}(3)$ = $\binom{12}{2}\binom{11}{2}$
- $f^{-1}(1)$ and $f^{-1}(3)$ = $\binom{12}{2}\binom{11}{2}$
- $f^{-1}(1)$, $f^{-1}(2)$ and $f^{-1}(3)$ = $\binom{13}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{7}{2}$

Final solution can be written as $S = C_0 - C_1 + C_2 - C_3$
Where $C_0 = 10^{13}$ is all possibilities
Hence $$S = 10^{13} - [\binom{13}{2} + \binom{12}{2} + \binom{13}{2}] + [\binom{12}{2}\binom{11}{2} + \binom{12}{2}\binom{11}{2} + \binom{12}{2}\binom{11}{2}] - [\binom{13}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{7}{2}]$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you've misunderstood something quite critical. In general, if $f:A\to B$ and $C\subseteq B,$ then the *preimage of* $C$ (with respect to $f$) is the set of all elements of $A$ mapped to $C$ by $f,$ which we denote (and define symbolically) by $$f^{-1}(C)=\{a\in A:f(a)\in C\}.$$

Consequently, $$\left\lvert f^{-1}\bigl(\{x\}\bigr)\right\rvert=2$$ means that exactly two elements of $A$ are mapped to $x$ by $f.$ For example, we could have $f^{-1}\bigl(\{1\}\bigr)=\{1,13\},$ $f^{-1}\bigl(\{2\}\bigr)=\{5,6\},$ $f^{-1}\bigl(\{3\}\bigr)=\{2,12\}.$

As an immediate consequence of this condition (plus surjectivity), this means that for $x\in\{4,5,...,9,10\}$ we will have $$\left\lvert f^{-1}\bigl(\{x\}\bigr)\right\rvert=1.$$ Our other condition then says that we want $$f^{-1}\bigl(\{x\}\bigr)\neq\{x-1\}$$ for each $x\in\{4,5,...,9,10\}.$ Can you see why?

We also want $x-1\notin f^{-1}\bigl(\{x\}\bigr)$ for $x\in\{2,3\},$ which my example above does *not* satisfy. Can you see why we need this, and why my example doesn't satisfy it? Can you take it from there?

---

**Edit**: You've made some good progress! There are still some issues with your solution, though.

> Now for conditions 1 and 2 together, $f^{-1}(1)$ and $f^{-1}(2)$ can be chosen in $\binom{13}{2}\cdot\binom{11}{2}$ ways, since after mapping 2 elements from A to x = 1, we are left with 11 elements, for x = 2 to choose, from which we cannot choose the element 1 since 2-1 = 1.

You've got the right idea, here, but your conclusion is not correct. Since we cannot allow $1$ to be an element of $f^{-1}\bigl(\{2\}\bigr),$ then we *may* have eleven elements to choose from, but *only if* $1\in f^{-1}\bigl(\{1\}\bigr).$ Otherwise, we'll have *ten* elements left to choose from. This leaves us needing to proceed by cases, which isn't very compatible with inclusion-exclusion. Similar issues occur with the rest of your attempt.

I will suggest again, as I did in the comments, that you first determine how many surjections $A\to B$ satisfy the condition $f(x)\neq x+1$ when $x\in\{1,2,...,12\},$ then exclude those which fail to satisfy the other condition.

Comment: So 2 elements can be mapped from B to A for each $x \in {1, 2, 3}$, giving us $\binom{13}{2}\cdot\binom{11}{2}\cdot\binom{9}{2}$ ways do so and leaving with 7 elements in A and 7 elements in B, where $f^{-1}\bigl(\{x\}\bigr)\neq\{x-1\}$ for each $x \in \{4,5, ...,9,10\}$ since 1, 2 and 3 have already been mapped to 2 elements each in A?

Comment: I think you've got the idea, though you're expressing it a bit differently than I would. Rather, the mapping goes from $A$ to $B.$ In particular, exactly two elements from $A$ are mapped into $\{x\}$ for each $x\in\{1,2,3\}.$ This does leave us with $7$ elements of $A$ whose target is not yet determined, and $7$ elements of $B$ which must be mapped to by $f$. Bear in mind that you'll need to verify whether all $\binom{13}2\cdot\binom{11}2\cdot\binom92$ ways of doing so will be compatible with the other condition. You may need to proceed by cases.

Comment: A better approach, to my mind, is to satisfy the other condition, first, as it's more restrictive.